# Proving square of nonzero integer is natural number

Tags: arithmetic

I am learning proofs with $\mathbb N$ and have this proposition: Let $m \in\mathbb Z$. If $m \ne 0$, then $m^2 \in\mathbb N$. Previously, I have proven: For $m \in\mathbb Z$, one and only one of the following is true: $m \in\mathbb N$, $-m \in\mathbb N$, $m = 0$.

If $m \ne 0$, then there are two cases to prove:

Case 1: $m \in\mathbb N$
That's straightforward because the product of two natural numbers is a natural number

Case 2: $-m \in\mathbb N$:

\begin{align*}
-m \cdot -m \in\mathbb N\\
(-1 \cdot -1) \cdot m \cdot m \in\mathbb N\\
m \cdot m \in\mathbb N\\
\end{align*}

What do you think?

Comment: For clarity sake, I'd state the three cases as m > 0 or m <0.  It's equivalent and makes no difference, but it's clearer to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m\in Z$,and if $m\ne0$, you've two cases.

Case 1: $m\in Z^+$
$$ => m^2 \in Z^+ => m^2 \in N$$ (Since multiplication within positive integers is closed, and results in a natural number always.)

Case 2: $m\in Z^-$
$$ => m^2 \in Z^+ => m^2 \in N$$
(Since multiplication within negative integers always results in a positive integer as you said by typing out the below :-)\begin{align*}
-m \cdot -m \in\mathbb N\\
(-1 \cdot -1) \cdot m \cdot m \in\mathbb N\\
m \cdot m \in\mathbb N\\
\end{align*}

QED

Your proof is perfect (it's essentially the same as mine!); I'd just suggest you say that *multiplication operation is closed for numbers picked from positive integers* instead of 'That's straightforward because the product of two natural numbers is a natural number' (In case you want to use a bit of terminology).

Otherwise it's completely fine!

Comment: Thank you very much! What do you mean by "completely closed"? It's the first time that I hear this. :)

Comment: I haven't said 'completely closed' anywhere. If you wish to know what 'closed' means... here's a link; It'll certainly help you! :)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove that: $(-m)(-m) = m\cdot m$.

By definition of $-m$ is that:

$m + (-m) = 0 \to (m+(-m))(m-(-m)) = 0(m+(-m)) = 0 \to m^2 - m(-m) + (-m)m - (-m)(-m) = 0 \to m^2 = (-m)(-m)$.